# Problem getting the height of a button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just can’t see what I’m doing wrong here. I create a button with this CSS

```
.displayBtn {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: #00FF00;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 2em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I tried two ways of getting the button height, & neither worked

```
    const btn = document.querySelector(".displayBtn");
    const btnStyle = getComputedStyle (btn);
    const btnHeight = btnStyle.style.offsetHeight;

    const btn = document.getElementsByClassName(".displayBtn");
    const btnHeight = btn[0].offsetHeight;
```

I’m including the full code in case it’s something I did elsewhere that’s causing the problem. The relevant section is between two rows of asterisks. I set btnHeight to 300px as a temporary fix.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="general.css">

<style>

figure {display: block;
        border-width:thin;
}
figcaption {background-color:yellow;}

#bigImg1 { display: none; } /* With this, hide button always works, 
                                         without it, hide button only works
                                         first time */

#img1, #img2, #img3 {
  background: url("bates-sprite.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  object-fit: none;
}

#img1 {object-position: 0 0;
  width:  816px; // full size 3264
  height: 612px; // full size 2448
}

.displayBtn {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: #00FF00;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 2em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<main>

<figure id="fig1">
    <figcaption>Camberley Mail</figcaption>
<script>
</script>
<div>
<p id="para">Text to go with picture.</p>
</div>
</figure>

<script>
"use strict";
const numberOfFigures = document.getElementsByTagName('figure').length;

// The function "insert" is used purely for debug purposes
function insert (figNum) {
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "OK so far" + figNum;
}

/* JavaScript arrays are 0 based, but I'm not using element[0] because I want the flag for each figure to be stored in bigImgExists[figNum] */
const bigImgExists = new Array(numberOfFigures + 1).fill(false);

// Insert all the buttons with thumbnail images.
for (let i=0; i < numberOfFigures; i++) imgBtn (i + 1);

function showBigImg(figNum) {

  if (!bigImgExists[figNum]) {
    // It doesn't exist, so create it.

    var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
    tempDiv.setAttribute("id", "bigImg" + figNum);
    tempDiv.style.backgroundColor = "white";

    tempDiv.innerHTML =  
        '<button type="button"' +
                 'class="displayBtn"' +
                 'onclick="hideBigImg (' + 
                                       figNum +
                                            ')">Hide large image</button>' +
        '<' + 'img id="img' + figNum + '" ' + 
                  'src="bates-sprite.jpeg"' +
                  'style="height: 100vh; ' +
                  'transform: translate(1000px,1000px) scale(2,2);">' /* 
                  scaling up the image leads to the top and left of the
                  picture being cut off, unless it is moved well to the right
                  and down. 1000px is a large but arbitrary figure. */

    const figcap = document.getElementById("fig" + figNum).firstElementChild;
    figcap.appendChild (tempDiv);  /* Append the button & big image to the
                                      figcaption */

    // Get the height and width of the image
    const element = document.querySelector('#img1');
    const style = getComputedStyle(element);
    const imgHeight = style.Height;
    const imgWidth = style.width;

    // Set the new position for the image.
    const img = document.getElementById ('img' + figNum);
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    img.style.top = -parseInt(imgHeight)/2 + "px"; // ☑️
    img.style.left = -parseInt(imgWidth)/2 + "px"; // ☑️

    /* Make tempDiv high enough to hold the scaled up image & make the
       accompanying text visible.
       IMPORTANT to do this AFTER creating & appending the image. */

//*********** problem getting btnHeight **********************

    //const btn = document.querySelector(".displayBtn");
    //const btnStyle = getComputedStyle (btn);
    //const btnHeight = btnStyle.style.offsetHeight;

    const btn = document.getElementsByClassName(".displayBtn");
    //const btnHeight = btn[0].offsetHeight;

    const btnHeight = "300px";

//*************************************************************

    tempDiv.style.height = 2*parseInt(imgHeight) + 
                           parseInt(btnHeight) +
                           "px";

    bigImgExists[figNum] = true;
  }

  document.getElementById('thumb' + figNum).style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('bigImg' + figNum).style.display = 'block';
}

function hideBigImg(figNum) {
document.getElementById('bigImg' + figNum).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('thumb' + figNum).style.display = 'block';
}

function imgBtn (figNum) {
//  Insert a button with thumbnail image
    let html = '<button type="button" ' +
                       'id="thumb' + figNum +
                     '" onclick="showBigImg (' + figNum + ')"></button>';

    const figcap = document.getElementById("fig" + figNum).firstElementChild;
    figcap.insertAdjacentHTML ("afterend", html);  /* Append the button to 
                                                      the figcaption */
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `btnStyle.style.offsetHeight` - no such style property as `offsetHeight` or `offset-height` ... so that won't work ... as for `btnHeight = btn[0].offsetHeight` - what is wrong with the value you get?

Comment: ahh, I see the issue ... you have no elements with the class `".displayBtn"` - but you will have one with `"displayBtn"` - `getElementsByClassName` looks for classes, so, no need for the `.` ... like `getElementById` wouldn't need the `#` ...

Comment: Or combine the 2 solutions you have there. `const btn = document.querySelector(".displayBtn");
const btnHeight = btn[0].offsetHeight;`

Comment: ‘’’const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("displayBtn");
    const btnHeight = btn[0].height;’’’ doesn’t cause the function to fall over, but it returns btnHeight as undefined. ‘’’const btnHeight = btn[0].offsetHeight;’’’ gives btnHeight as zero.

Comment: Re "`width:  816px; // full size 3264`": `//` is not a valid comment character sequence in CSS (only the C-style one is, `/*  */`). This is also indicated by the weird ***syntax highlighting***. It *will* break in some browsers (e.g., it may ignore all or part of the rest of the CSS (terminate parsing)).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the problem [Jaromanda spotted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73564243/problem-getting-the-height-of-a-button-with-javascript/73575496#comment129907513_73564243) (searching for class `.displayBtn`), I had also set `#bigImg1 { display: none; }` at an earlier stage. This was why the button height was `undefined`.